# Python 3.7 How to Connect Two PC With Socket Module

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to connect two computers with python and transmit data between them. I searched Google and get a code like this.

```
# Save as client.py 
# Message Sender
import os
from socket import *
host = "192.168.0.11" # set to IP address of target computer
port = 13000
addr = (host, port)
UDPSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
while True:
    data = input("Enter message to send or type 'exit': ")
    UDPSock.sendto(data.encode('utf-8'), addr)
    if data == "exit":
        break
UDPSock.close()
os._exit(0)

# Save as server.py 
# Message Receiver
import os
from socket import *
host = "" # I'm not sure what to put here
port = 13000
buf = 1024
addr = (host, port)
UDPSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
UDPSock.bind(addr)
print ("Waiting to receive messages...")
while True:
    (data, addr) = UDPSock.recvfrom(buf)
    print ("Received message: " + data)
    if data == "exit":
        break
UDPSock.close()
os._exit(0)
```

When I try to sent messages,I found that the message was send but the other computer didn't receive anything...What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than needing `data = data.decode()` after your `recvfrom` in the client, the code should work.  I tested your code with `host = 'localhost'` on the client and ran both the client and server on the same computer and it worked.  You may need to adjust your firewall to allow UDP traffic on port 13000 on one or both computers.